# What's the name of the case value?

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2

switch {
    case ONE: {
        return ONE * ONE;
    }

    case TWO: {
        return TWO * TWO;
    }
}
```

and I want to do this:

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2

switch {
    case ONE:
    case TWO:
     {
        return name_of_the_case_value * name_of_the_case_value;
    }

}
```

Now, what do I put instead of name_of_the_case_value? Something that works for both ONE or TWO.
Is there a pre-defined variable, like __name_of_the_case_value, that holds the name of the current case value?

Comment: Assuming you meant `switch(val)` then `val * val` does what you want doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you. It's much clearer now. All the examples I've seen so far used val only on the same row with switch, and I though that val's purpose was only for checking against the case values. As simple as it looks now, I've never thought of val as the value I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever variable you put in the `switch(variable)` part you just just reuse in the case itself.

e.g.

```
int var;

//some code that sets the value of var

switch(var){
    case ONE:
    case TWO:
        return var * var;
    default:
        break;
}
```

You can't just have

```
switch{
    case WHATEVER1:
    case WHATEVER2:
    etc...
}
```

`case` relates to the value of a variable/expression that needs to be there at the start of the `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have this:

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2

switch {
    case ONE: {
        return ONE * ONE;
    }

    case TWO: {
        return TWO * TWO;
    }
}
```

`switch` needs a value to switch according to... So you have:

```
switch (my_value) {
    case ONE: {
        return ONE * ONE;
    }

    case TWO: {
        return TWO * TWO;
    }
}
```

Hence your question is answered, as you can use `my_value` in the `case`.

Answer (score 0):

This construction

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2

switch {
    case ONE: {
        return ONE * ONE;
    }

    case TWO: {
        return TWO * TWO;
    }
}
```

is invalid because switch statement requires an expression. The case labels correspond to possible values of the expression. So if the control was passed to for example case ONE: then it means that the value of the expression is equal to ONE. Taking this into account you can write

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2

switch ( expr ) {
    case ONE: 
    case TWO: {
        return expr * expr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that? You wouldn't. You would write `return expr*expr` and leave it at that. Unless you meant to write a `default` case and have it throw an exception, which you should probably do.